# Setting `linebreaks` etc. in `tikz environments` generated as `\_tl` variables

Tags: tikz-pgf, expl3

Using the key values defined in `\NewDocumentCommand\myShowTree` parameter `#1` calls the `\cs_` function `\rnTikZ_showTree:n` which in turn calls `\cs_` functions `\rn_tikzStyle_FR` and `\rn_tikzContent_FR:n` which generate `style` and `content` for the `tikzpicture` environment to draw a binary search tree. In this MWE parameter `#1` passed to `\rnTikZ_showTree:n` is a dummy, and the way `style` and `content` are generated are mimicked - the purpose of the MWE is merely to illustrate difficulties I am having representing certain information in nodes, in particular `linebreaks`. Sections 1 and 2 draw the tree as native `tikz` pictures, i.e. with the `tikzpicture` environment manually defined. There are no problems whatsoever with defining individual node styles, defining line breaks or setting colors and text styles etc. in node content. Section 3 operates with a `tikzpicture` environment using externally generated `\_tl` variables defining the `style` and `content` portions. All good until enhancements are attempted.
ERR 1: compiles, but does not recognise `subscripts`, although `superscript` works
ERR 2 to 4: `!Use of \@newline doesn't match its definition`.
Surprisingly, setting node styles on the fly cause no problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. Sunday 17 December 2017
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__rn_start_tikzpicture:n 
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__rn_start_tikzpicture:n { V }

\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl
\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxTwo_tl
\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxThree_tl

\tl_new:N \g_rn_tikzStyle_FR_tl
\cs_new:Npn \rn_tikzStyle_FR:n #1
%  PARAMETERS #1: dummy variable 
%  RETURNS \g_rn_tikzStyle_FR_tl for plugging into the tikzpicture     environment
  {
\group_begin:
    \tl_gset:Nx \g_rn_tikzStyle_FR_tl {level~distance=15mm,
    every~node/.style={rectangle,draw,inner~sep=2pt,align=left},
    level 1/.style={sibling~distance=50mm},
    level 2/.style={sibling~distance=25mm}}  
\group_end:
  }  %  \rn_tikzStyle_FR:n

\tl_new:N \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl
\cs_new:Npn \rn_tikzContent_FR:n #1
    %  RETURNS \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl for plugging into the tikzpicture environment
  {
\group_begin:
    % the nodes are visited post-order to generate tikzContent:
    % visiting node key = 6:    
    \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl {child[missing]}
    \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxOne_tl {6}
    \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxTwo_tl {child{node{\l_rn_auxOne_tl}}}
    \tl_gput_right:NV \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl {\l_rn_auxTwo_tl}
    % visiting node key = 4:
    \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxOne_tl {4}
% ERR 1:    \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxOne_tl {4:$x_3^2$}
    \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxTwo_tl {node{\l_rn_auxOne_tl}}
    \tl_gput_left:NV \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl {\l_rn_auxTwo_tl}
    \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxThree_tl {\g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl}
    \tl_gset:Nx \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl {child{\l_rn_auxThree_tl}}
    % visiting node key = 10:
    \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxOne_tl {10}
% ERR 2:    \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxOne_tl {\color{red}10}
%    \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxTwo_tl {child{node{\l_rn_auxOne_tl}}}
    \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxTwo_tl {child{node[circle,draw,inner~sep=2pt]   {\l_rn_auxOne_tl}}}  % this works well!
    \tl_gput_right:NV \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl \l_rn_auxTwo_tl
    % visiting root, key = 8:
    \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxOne_tl {8}
% ERR 3   \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxOne_tl {8\\BF:+1}
% ERR 4   \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxOne_tl {\textbf{8}}
    \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxTwo_tl {\exp_not:N \node{\l_rn_auxOne_tl}}
    \tl_gput_left:NV \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl \l_rn_auxTwo_tl
\group_end:
  }  %  \rn_tikzContent_FR:n

\cs_new:Npn \rnTikZ_showTree:n #1  
  {
\group_begin:
  \rn_tikzContent_FR:n {#1}
  \rn_tikzStyle_FR:n {2}
  \__rn_start_tikzpicture:V \g_rn_tikzStyle_FR_tl        
    \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\group_end:
  }  %  \rnTikZ_showTree:n

\NewDocumentCommand\myShowTree{O{5,3,4,7}}
  {
    \rnTikZ_showTree:n {#1}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\section{Native tikzpicture: Basic}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=15mm,
every node/.style={rectangle,draw,inner sep=2pt,align=left},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=50mm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=25mm}]
\node{8}child{node{4}child[missing]child{node{6}}}child{node{10}};
\end{tikzpicture} 

\section{Native tikzpicture: Enhanced node content}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=15mm,
every node/.style={rectangle,draw,inner sep=2pt,align=left},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=50mm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=25mm}]
\node{\textbf{8}\\BF:+1\\H:2\\W:4}child{node{4\\$x_3^2$}child[missing]child {node{6\\$\alpha_2$}}}child{node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt]{\color{red}10}};
\end{tikzpicture} 

\section{`tikzpicture` environment generated}
\myShowTree[8,4,6,10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't pass ``\\`` to something subject to `\tl_set:Nx`; are you sure you need full expansion? Possibly `\exp_not:V \l_rn_auxOne_tl` is what you need.

Comment: Inside your `expl3`code you have `level 1` which should probably be `level~1`, ditto for `level 2`.

Comment: I don't think your code really has `\tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxOne_tl {4:$x_3^2$}`; you probably are passing this via an argument or key-value syntax. I understand you want to keep the example simple, but this doesn't help. And `\tl_set:Nx` does nothing particular here. Since `_` is a letter in that context, use `\sb`.

Comment: I now recall having had the `\sb` issue previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you're doing, because it would be a waste of time hard coding the parameters in the definitions.

Anyway, you need `\exp_not:V` when passing a token list to `\tl_set:Nx` (or similar), so the value is extracted but not expanded further.

I marked with `% <-- !!` the lines I changed, there are other small adjustments to be done. In general, one should not abuse `x`-expansion.

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. Sunday 17 December 2017
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__rn_start_tikzpicture:n 
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__rn_start_tikzpicture:n { V }

\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl
\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxTwo_tl
\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxThree_tl

\tl_new:N \g_rn_tikzStyle_FR_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \rn_tikzStyle_FR:n #1 % <--- !!
%  PARAMETERS #1: dummy variable 
%  RETURNS \g_rn_tikzStyle_FR_tl for plugging into the tikzpicture     environment
  {
\group_begin:
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_rn_tikzStyle_FR_tl {level~distance=15mm, % <--- !!
    every~node/.style={rectangle,draw,inner~sep=2pt,align=left},
    level~1/.style={sibling~distance=50mm}, % <--- !!
    level~2/.style={sibling~distance=25mm}} % <--- !!
\group_end:
  }  %  \rn_tikzStyle_FR:n

\tl_new:N \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \rn_tikzContent_FR:n #1 % <--- !!
    %  RETURNS \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl for plugging into the tikzpicture environment
  {
\group_begin:
    % the nodes are visited post-order to generate tikzContent:
    % visiting node key = 6:    
    \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl {child[missing]} % <--- !!
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl {6}
    \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxTwo_tl {child{node{\exp_not:V \l_rn_auxOne_tl}}} % <--- !!
    \tl_gput_right:NV \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl \l_rn_auxTwo_tl % <--- !!
    % visiting node key = 4:
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl {4:$x\sb3^2$} % <--- !!
    \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxTwo_tl {node{\exp_not:V \l_rn_auxOne_tl}} % <--- !!
    \tl_gput_left:NV \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl \l_rn_auxTwo_tl % <--- !!
    \tl_set_eq:NN \l_rn_auxThree_tl \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl % <--- !!
    \tl_gset:Nx \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl {child{\exp_not:V \l_rn_auxThree_tl}} % <--- !!
    % visiting node key = 10:
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl {\color{red}10} % <--- !!
    \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxTwo_tl {child{node{\exp_not:V \l_rn_auxOne_tl}}} % <--- !!
    \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxTwo_tl
     {
      child{node[circle,draw,inner~sep=2pt] {\exp_not:V \l_rn_auxOne_tl}}
     } % <--- !!
    \tl_gput_right:NV \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl \l_rn_auxTwo_tl
    % visiting root, key = 8:
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl {8\\BF:+1} % <--- !!
    \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxTwo_tl {\exp_not:N \node{\exp_not:V \l_rn_auxOne_tl}} % <--- !!
    \tl_gput_left:NV \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl \l_rn_auxTwo_tl
\group_end:
  }  %  \rn_tikzContent_FR:n

\cs_new_protected:Npn \rnTikZ_showTree:n #1   % <--- !!
  {
\group_begin:
  \rn_tikzContent_FR:n {#1}
  \rn_tikzStyle_FR:n {2}
  \__rn_start_tikzpicture:V \g_rn_tikzStyle_FR_tl        
    \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\group_end:
  }  %  \rnTikZ_showTree:n

\NewDocumentCommand\myShowTree{O{5,3,4,7}}
  {
    \rnTikZ_showTree:n {#1}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\section{Native tikzpicture: Basic}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=15mm,
every node/.style={rectangle,draw,inner sep=2pt,align=left},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=50mm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=25mm}]
\node{8}child{node{4}child[missing]child{node{6}}}child{node{10}};
\end{tikzpicture} 

\section{Native tikzpicture: Enhanced node content}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=15mm,
every node/.style={rectangle,draw,inner sep=2pt,align=left},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=50mm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=25mm}]
\node{\textbf{8}\\BF:+1\\H:2\\W:4}child{node{4\\$x_3^2$}child[missing]child {node{6\\$\alpha_2$}}}child{node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt]{\color{red}10}};
\end{tikzpicture} 

\section{`tikzpicture` environment generated}
\myShowTree[8,4,6,10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Bingo! Solves my problems completely.